# Spring Date Format

Tags: java, spring, datetime, spring-boot

I have an angular app which send me a date like this dd/MM/yyyy.
I would like to insert this date in the database.
Here is my entity

```
@Entity
public class Individu implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String nui;
    private int civility; 
    private String lastName;
    private String useName;
    private String firstName;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date birthDate;
```

but when i run my SpringBootApp i always have this error:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` from String "20/02/1990": not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '20/02/1990': Cannot parse date "20/02/1990": not compatible with any of standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

Is some one have a solution for me?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `@DateTimeFormat` annotation and change to [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html)?

Comment: I have the same error bad request. The solution is using @JsonFormat like describe below

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need `@JsonFormat`:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
private Date birthDate;
```

Comment: is it possible for me to parse also a date like yyyy-MM-dd in this date. for example to have a JsonfFromat like this @JsonFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy, yyyy-MM-dd")?